# Deixar input envolto com traços ao usar Jquery Validate

Tags: css, jquery-validate

Estou usando o plugin Jquey Validation e estou tentando deixar a marcação de erro no input como na imagem que estou passando em anexo, tentei algumas alternativas e o resultado não foi o esperado, o que tenho:

```
$("#frmLaudo").validate({
// Regras
rules: {
    ID: {
        required:true,
    },              
    Cooperante: {
        required:true
    },
    Propriedade: {
        required:true
    },
    UF: {
        required:true
    },
    Municipio: {
        required:true
    }                               
},
// Messages for form validation
messages: {
    ID: {
        required: 'Por favor informe o ID'
    },              
    Cooperante: {
        required: 'Por favor informe o nome'
    },
    Propriedade: {
        required: 'Por favor informe a propriedade'                 
    },
    UF: {
        required: 'Por favor informe a UF'                  
    },  
    Municipio: {
        required: 'Por favor informe o Municipio'                   
    }                           
},
...
```

O css que tentei deixaria o fundo em vermelho, mas não é o que preciso, vejam:

```
label.error{
  display: none!important;
}

.error{
  background-color: red;
}
```

O que realmente preciso é o que se vê nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão:

> jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.0 - 2/4/2013

Comment: Olá @Marconi, já tentei, mas a marcação não aparece.

Comment: Opa tenta assim `border: 2px dashed red;`. Esse Css quer diz 2px de espessura, stilo tracejado com cor vermelha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está certo, isso que você fez:

```
.error{
  background-color: red;
}
```

vai deixar o fundo vermelho. Como você quer a borda tracejada deve colocar:

```
.error{
  background-color: #FDFBFB;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Essa cor `#FDFBFB;` é a cor que está no seu exemplo, se deixar o background com `red` não vai diferenciar a borda e fica difícil a visualização do `placeholder`.

Você pode ver outros exemplos de borda no site da [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp).